# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2) when reading a json?

Tags: python, json

```
{
  "teams": {
    "sp": [
      {
        "k": {
          "attack": 3,
          "defense": 4
        },
        "s": {
          "attack": 3,
          "defense": 4
        },
        "b": {
          "attack": 3,
          "defense": 4
        },
        "h": {
          "attack": 3,
          "defense": 4
        },
        "r": {
          "attack": 3,
          "defense": 4
        },
        "l": {
          "attack": 4,
          "defense": 5
        }
      }
    ],
    "mu": [
      {
        "r": {
          "attack": 5,
          "defense": 6
        },
        "a": {
          "attack": 4,
          "defense": 3
        },
        "f": {
          "attack": 4,
          "defense": 3
        },
        "c": {
          "attack": 4,
          "defense": 3
        },
        "v": {
          "attack": 4,
          "defense": 2
        },
        "dg": {
          "attack": 4,
          "defense": 5
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Code

```
obj = [json.loads(line) for line in open('playerlist.json', 'r')]
print(obj)
```

the above `json` is player list and below is the python code I'm trying to read it with. when I run it it raise

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

I've read its a formatting issue with the `json` but when I run it through a `json` formatted it says it is valid `json`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to convert individual lines to `json`, you need to convert the all file at once

```
with open('playerlist.json', 'r') as f:
    obj = json.load(f)
```